Can't change geometry in GeoPandas
I have an extremely strange issue with my code.
I have a dataframe with 2 columns with point geometries, startgeom and endgeom.
I want to assign a geometry from startgeom, do some calculations and then change my geometry based on endgeom. Startgeom is in 4326 projection and endgeom in 32632.
Unfortunately while it seems simple, the geometry does not change!!
Have a look at my code.
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely import wkt

df=pd.read_csv(r"C:data/sample.csv")
df['startgeom'] = df['startgeom'].apply(wkt.loads)
df['endgeom'] = df['endgeom'].apply(wkt.loads)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=df["startgeom"],crs=4326)
gdf=gdf.to_crs(32632)
gdf

new = gdf.set_geometry("endgeom",crs=32632)

Printing the "new" geodataframe I get the old geometry! How is this possible?
EDIT: Actually "geometry" column does not change, but new.geometry changes correctly. Why is that?

Please edit your question to include a small sample of "sample.csv"

Do my answer work? If so: What should I do when someone answers my question?

You can't set the geometry to endgeom column where the points are in lat/long and specify the crs as 32632:
new = gdf.set_geometry("endgeom", crs=32632)

You need to do:
new = gdf.set_geometry("endgeom", crs=4326)
new.to_crs(32632, inplace=True)

